# chart.js tooltips empty space below text

Tags: javascript, chart.js2

I've got a chart.js scatter chart which provides survey respondent rationale for the scores they've given when you hover over that point.  This works nicely, but:

- certain characters are rendering incorrectly (so far I've only found this example of ' rendering incorrectly as &#39, but I assume there would be a family of less common punctuation items that might turn up.)  This is occurring in both Chrome and IE11. Django and Chart.js claim to be 100% happy with UTF-8, and it is specified (charset='utf8') as an attribute in the html meta.
  ANSWER: the django template filter |escapejs applied to each string.
- The 'rationale' strings (up to 200 chars I think) mostly go into the 'afterLabel' field, which for some reason extends to the chart horizontal axis from wherever it starts, leaving a lot of empty space and a weird look.
- I need help writing javascript because if you look at the way I've built these call-backs, they line-break the whole 'rationale' to get the first line (for the Label) and the second-thru-nth lines (for afterLabel).

[image]

<del>Data is populated from a Django application and the text is put into the chart using the Django template system; I don't think this is anything to do with Django.  Is there a chart.js config option I need to enable, or do I need to switch to html rendering of labels?</del>  See ANSWER to part1, above.

This is the template:

```
{% block Chart %}

<div class="container" style="width:65vw" >
<canvas id="canvas{{ temp_summary.question }}" class="chart-js-render-monitor" width="300" height="300"> 

</canvas>

</div>
<script>
        var color = Chart.helpers.color;
        var scatterChartData = {

            datasets: [{
                label: "Maxima",
                pointRadius: 10,
                pointHoverRadius: 12,
                borderColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.5)',
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.5)',                                                    
                labels: [{% for row in data_series %} "{{ row.6}}", {%endfor%} ], 
                data: [
{% for row in data_series %}
                {
                    x:  "{{ row.0 }}",
                    y: "{{ row.2 }}",   
                }, 
{% endfor %}                                                 
]
            },

            {
                label: "Minima",
                pointRadius: 10,
                pointHoverRadius: 12,
                borderColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.5)',
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.5)',
                labels: [{% for row in data_series %} "{{ row.5}}", {%endfor%} ],                                       
                data: [
{% for row in data_series %} 
                {                        
                    x:  "{{ row.0 }}",
                    y: "{{ row.1 }}",
                }, 
{% endfor %}                         
                        ]
            }, {
                label: "Estima",
                pointRadius: 10,
                pointHoverRadius: 12,
                borderColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)',
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)',
                labels: [{% for row in data_series %} "{{ row.7}}", {%endfor%} ],                                       
                data: [
{% for row in data_series %}  
                {
                    x:  "{{ row.0 }}",
                    y: "{{ row.3 }}",

                }, 
{% endfor %}                         
                        ]
            }

             ]
        }; 


        var formatString = function(string, allowed_width, for_label) {
            var length = string.length;
            var paraLength = allowed_width;
            var paragraphs = [];
            for (var i=0; i < allowed_width; i++) {
                var marker = paraLength;
                //if the marker is right after a space, move marker back one character
                if (string.charAt(marker-1) == " ") {
                    marker--; 
                }
                //move marker to end of a word if it's in the middle
                while(string.charAt(marker) != " " && string.charAt(marker) != "") {
                    marker++;
                }
                var nextPara = string.substring(0, marker)
                paragraphs.push(nextPara)
                string = string.substring((nextPara.length+1),string.length)
            }
            if (for_label) {return paragraphs[0] };  // label is the first line
            if (!for_label) {return paragraphs.slice(1)};  // afterlabel is a subsequent line
        };


        window.onload = function() {  // scatter_chart
            var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas{{ temp_summary.question }}").getContext("2d");
            window.myScatter = Chart.Scatter(ctx, {
                data: scatterChartData,
                options: {
                    layout: {
                             padding: {
                                      left: 11,
                                      right: 11,
                                      bottom: 11,
                                      top: 11,},
                             },    
                     scales: {
                         xAxes: [{
                            type: 'linear',
                            position: 'bottom',
                            ticks: {
                                 min: 0.8,   
                                 padding: 11,
                                 stepSize: 1,

                                     }
                                  }]
                             },
                    title: {
                        display: true,
                        text: 'Maxima, Minima and Estima by User'
                    },
                    fill: false,
                    showLines: false,
                    tooltips: {
                       callbacks: {
                            label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                                    var text1 = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].labels[tooltipItem.index]                                    
                                    return formatString(text1, 60, true)                                    
                                    },
                            afterLabel: function(tooltipItem, data){                                    
                                    var text2 = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].labels[tooltipItem.index]
                                    return formatString(text2, 60, false)
                                    },
                                    },


                                    }
                                }



                }
            );
        };

    </script>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Please do not edit your question with the answer inside: instead, move your solution by replying with your own answer post.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to bullet 1 (characters presented incorrectly) was that I was naive in thinking that:

```
labels: [{% for row in data_series %} "{{ row.6}}", {%endfor%} ],
```

could always be understood by the javascript engine. If a label (row.6) contained a ' or a ", the javascript engine made the best of it, but those characters (and others) need to be correctly escaped with a leading "\".  Django does this for you with the template tag |escapejs.

My question about the height setting for these labels is still one I haven't solved.